# Destructing stack object vs deleting heap-allocated object of non-final class with virtual functions

Tags: c++, destructor, final, virtual-functions

Let's say you have a derived class with virtual functions and non-virtual destructor like:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual void foo() {}
};
```

And let's say you create a heap-allocated object of a `Derived` class and delete it using `delete` keyword like:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived();
    delete d;
}
```

Compiling this code with `-Wall -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Werror` flags will throw you an error which is totally fine because it might eventually cause UB. Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++%7EBase()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Derived+:+public+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Derived()+%7B%7D%0A++++virtual+void+foo()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Derived+*d+%3D+new+Derived()%3B%0A++++delete+d%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.33578104138851,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Obviously, calling a destructor of `d` object is what's causing the compiler error because following code has the same result (at least on [CLANG](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++%7EBase()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Derived+:+public+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Derived()+%7B%7D%0A++++virtual+void+foo()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Derived+d%3B%0A++++d.%7EDerived()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.33578104138851,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+11.0.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), [GCC](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++%7EBase()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Derived+:+public+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Derived()+%7B%7D%0A++++virtual+void+foo()+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Derived+d%3B%0A++++d.%7EDerived()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.33578104138851,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) has no problem with the following code):

```cpp
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.~Derived();
}
```

But if I create a simple object on stack, there is no compiler errors for both CLANG and GCC:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

We all know that `Derived` class' destructor is being called at the end of `main` function, but why there is no errors in such case?

Comment: Manually calling the destructor is not illegal (even if incorrect here), so why would it produce an error?

Comment: @super I would expect it to produce an error because `delete` is producing the error and `delete` calls object's destructor if I am not mistaken. However, maybe the error is raised only in case of runtime polymorphism and CLANG has a bug when manually calling destructor on stack object.

Comment: IMHO the compiler is right. It does not know if d points to an instance of Derived, it can point to an object of a derived class of the Derived. Use the keyword final.

Comment: @S.M. I know that the keyword final would fix the thing, but I was just interested in why it happens in some cases and in some not.

Comment: It's not an error in this context, it's a warning for case if you try to delete  some Derived's descendant. THis code isn't ill-formed, just `-Werror` prevents it from being compiled.

Comment: If you create an object on stack, the compiler knows the exact type. If you create an object on heap, the compiler does not know the type. It's obvious. The compiler could analyse the simple code you shown, but such a simple code does not used in the world, so it does not perform (static) analysis for such cases. It's impossible to know the type of the pointee in other cases (real code).

Comment: @S.M. ok now i get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object has automatic storage duration or is a member of a class, polymorphism need not be considered. In the code given, the lvalue `d` cannot reference a more-derived object. Therefore, calling `Derived::~Derived` is always correct and need not be warned about.

Comment: So this is a CLANG's bug?

Comment: @NutCracker When I talk about calling `Derived::~Derived`, I mean the implicit calls that the compiler inserts. The explicit call that you show in the code is wrong anyway, and if the compiler warns about it for whatever reason, all the better.

Comment: Ok I get it. Tnx